# How to consume a compile-time only enum from DefinitelyTyped?

Tags: typescript, twitter-bootstrap, definitelytyped

I want to use the package `@types/bootstrap` to add type hinting when creating event listeners on Bootstrap components, such as the `Carousel.Events.slide` enum member:

```
/* node_modules/@types/bootstrap/.../carousel.d.ts */
enum Events {
    slide = 'slide.bs.carousel',
}

/* index.ts */
declare const Carousel: typeof import("bootstrap").Carousel;

myCarouselElement.addEventListener(Carousel.Events.slide, e => {
    // compiler knows about 'relatedTarget' from 'carousel.d.ts'
    const active = e.relatedTarget;
});
```

However, since the package exports a regular enum, the emitted JavaScript retains the `Carousel.Events.slide` call (which doesn't exist in Bootstrap), rather then supplying it with the `slide.bs.carousel` value. Bad practices aside, I could edit my copy of the `carousel.d.ts` file and declare `Events` as a `const enum`, which would inline the enum value; however, this has [its own problems](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enum-pitfalls) and isn't a suitable solution for the DefinitelyTyped repo.

How should I correctly be importing enums? Can I somehow alias my import as a `const enum`?

Comment: Not sure if this is applicable for your specific scenario, but if it would be possible to write your import like `import { Carousel} from 'bootstrap';` you could then instead write `import type { Carousel } from 'bootstrap';`.
The `import type` is completely emitted when compiling to javascript and only relevant for typescript.

Comment: @Grochni `declare const` does the same thing, it's removed as well. However, importing `Carousel` as a type wouldn't work because `@types/bootstrap` exports `Carousel` as both a `class` and a `namespace`, and declaring it as `type { Carousel }` would cause the enum declared in the namespace to not be accessible (`Carousel.Events.slide`).

Comment: Isn't this an error in the type definition file? I mean if that enum is not there in bootstrap then why is it declared as one?